# In Microsoft Graph Explorer Multipart boundary generates malformed json Syntax error

Tags: html, json, microsoft-graph-api, office365, multipart

I am trying to upload a small file to Sharepoint in Microsoft Graph Explorer using Multipart MIME. The content-type contains a string for boundary and the HTML data uses the boundary to separate the parts. But Microsoft Graph Explorer seems to only take JSON. It seems simple, but what am I missing here? Even if the content-type header is set to text/html, it still wants JSON in the body!!!

Comment: Did you wanna complain the Ms Graph Explore can't post other format of reqestBody except JSON？ If so, from the document I find a point to describe it:
The POST, PATCH, and PUT methods require a request body, usually specified in JSON format, that contains additional information, such as the values for properties of the resource.
So would you mind changing a tool such as postman?

Comment: I am just trying to validate some Postman results with a second tool.

Comment: I see, and how about trying chrome's add-in **Talend Api test**?

Comment: Thanks but my question is aimed at one specific tool.